# Output a sequence of ten numbers to console

Tags: c#, .net, loops, console-application

The user must provide the starting point and indicate whether the sequence should be ascending or descending. Thus far it starts counting and never stops.  How do I make it stop after increment it by 10. Would I use an if statement to let the user choose to make it ascending or descending?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int val;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number!");

        val = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = val; i <= (val + 10); val++)
            Console.WriteLine(val);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for not using debugger ...

Comment: @Fichermaen i have only been doing C# for one month now so yeah i am noob and dont really know how to debug to well just yet or step through the code but thanx for the tip will do next time

Answer (score 7):

It never stops because you increase `val`, and `i` will always be less than `val + 10` (you never increase `i`). You should increase `i` instead, and use `i` inside the loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{           
    int val;            

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number!");

    val = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                                 

    for (int i = val; i <= (val + 10); i++)
      Console.WriteLine(i);            

    Console.ReadLine();         

}
```

For the ascending vs. descending part, you also need to take a second input from the user and if he choose descending, make a loop that checks if `i >= (val - 10)`, and that goes `i--` each iteration instead.

Comment: Thanx allot and yeah it should have been tagged as homework lol going through a book a friend gave me but it has no solutions to the work.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        const char down = '-';

        Console.Write("Please enter a number! n[{0}]:", down);
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        char ch = input.Last();
        int diff = (ch == down) ? -1 : 1;
        int val = Int32.Parse(input.TrimEnd(down));

        for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++, val += diff)
            Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
}
```

**DEMO**

```
Please enter a number! n[-]:10-
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

Please enter a number! n[-]:5
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{           
    int val;            

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number!");

    val = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                                 

    for (int i = val; i <= (val + 10); i++)
        Console.WriteLine(i);            

    Console.ReadLine();         
}
```

Comment: Still wrong. This will output the same number 10 times inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{           
int val, isDecrement;            
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number!");
val = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());      

Console.WriteLine("Please enter 1 to go Descending order!");   
isDecrement = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

if(isDecrement ==1)
{
   for (int i = val; i >= (val - 10); i--)
     Console.WriteLine(i);            
}
else
{
for (int i = val; i <= (val + 10); i++)
  Console.WriteLine(i);            
}
Console.ReadLine();         

}
```